# Ansible loop over multiple lists of variables

Tags: linux, ansible, snmp

i hope everyone can help me with my ansible task problem. I deploy the snmp configurations via ansible on my servers and work with snmp-extend to trigger my scripts over snmp with certain OIDs. After my playbook has run and ansible deploy the snmp configurations, i manually execute the following command to become the OID for certain extend, for example:

```
snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.\"folder-size-/home\"
```

This part i would like to do automatically via ansible, i have the variables:

```
snmp_mountpoints_extends:
  - folder-size
  - folder-avail
  - folder-used
```

and in my inventory I define for host the following variables:

```
server1:
  custom_mountpoints:
    - /home
    - /opt
```

my ansible part:

```
 name: Generate OIDs for custom inventroy variables
  become: yes
  shell: 'snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.\"{{ item }}-{{ custom_mountpoints[0] }}\"'
  with_items:
     "{{ snmp_mountpoints_extends }}"
  register: custom_mountpoints_output
  when:
    - custom_mountpoints is defined

- name: print output from custom_mountpoints_output
  debug: msg={{ custom_mountpoints_output }}
```

This work fine but only for first host variable /home. How can I iterate over my custom_mountpoints with each vars from snmp_mountpoints_extends?

thank you in advance

Comment: What does the expected matrix look like? Abstract the problem, e.g. `l1: [f1, f2, f3]` `l2:[a, b]`. The SNMP story is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

According Ansible documentation [Iterating over nested lists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-nested-lists) you may use the following approach

```yaml
--- 
- hosts:localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    server1:
      custom_mountpoints:
        - /home
        - /opt

    snmp_mountpoints_extends:
      - folder-size
      - folder-avail
      - folder-used

  tasks:

  - name: Iterating over nested lists
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item[0] }} and {{ item[1] }}"
    loop: "{{ server1.custom_mountpoints | product(snmp_mountpoints_extend) | list }}"
```

resulting into the desired output.

```
/home and folder-size
/home and folder-avail
/home and folder-used
/opt and folder-size
/opt and folder-avail
/opt and folder-used
```

Comment: Hi @U880D,

thank you very much! A question about it.

`loop: "{{ server1.custom_mountpoints | product(snmp_mountpoints_extend) | list }}"`

What if I have more then one Server1?

Comment: @tracestats, If you have more than one server, you'll need to provide them as list too, in example `serverlist: server1: ... server2: ... etc:`.

Comment: it works! merci