# Double loop in ansible

Tags: automation, ansible, redhat

I am trying to use a double loop in order to create an LVM for the disks detected and then mount the LVM created to a specific path.

Intil now I can use `with_items` to create the LVM but I cannot find a way to automate the creation of the LVM with the specific "application" variable for >= 3 disks.

PS: *application* I use for the lv/vg name and the path

Example: for sda, sdb, sdc

- sda: will be skipped since it's already partionned from template
- sdb: I will use the name postgres ==> vg-postgres & lv-postgres & /opt/postgres
- sdc: I will use the name  data ===> vg-data & lv-data & /opt/data

How can this be done?

*main.yml*

```yaml
---
- name: get a list of block devices (excludes loop and child devices)
  command: lsblk -n -o NAME --nodeps --exclude 7
  register: lsblk_out
 
- include_tasks: lvm.yml
  with_items: '{{ lsblk_out.stdout_lines }}'
  when: sdx != 'sda'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: sdx
```

*lvm.yml*

```yaml
---
- name: task for creating volume group with disk {{ sdx }}
  lvg:
    vg: vg-{{application}}
    pvs: /dev/{{ sdx }}
    pesize: 16
    state: present
   
- name: task for creating logical volume
  lvol:
    vg: vg-{{application}}
    lv:  lv-{{application}}
    size: 100%FREE
    force: yes
    state: present

- name: Create a ext4 filesystem on lvm "/dev/{{ sdx }}".
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    dev: "/dev/vg-{{application}}/lv-{{application}}"
    force: no

- name: Create a directory to mount the filesystem.
  file:
    path: "/opt/{{application}}"
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'

- name: Mount the created  filesystem.
  mount:
    path: "/opt/{{application}}"
    src: "/dev/vg-{{application}}/lv-{{application}}"
    fstype: ext4
    opts: defaults
    state: mounted
```

Comment: sorry but i dont understand your problem, where you have 2 loops....the best way to explain better will be to show the content of different variables and the final result you want...

Comment: Because of your statement "_I am trying to use a double loop_" you may have a look into the example of [Complex (Nested) Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-nested-lists) or [loop over multiple lists of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71668363/6771046).

Comment: Hello @Frenchy, I ve got the list of disks which will be used to configure the LVM, so for example with sdx=sdb the task lvm will create an Lvm with an application variable that I will enter, my question will be how I use a list in {application} variable and can be able to when configuring sdb it will use item 1 from {application} , item 2 with sdc , item 3 with sdd etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are lot of solutions, you could use a dictionary:

```
- include_tasks: lvm.yml
  with_items: '{{ lsblk_out.stdout_lines }}'
  when: sdx != 'sda'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: sdx
  vars:
    listsdx:
      sdb: item1
      sdc: item2
    application: "{{  listsdx[sdx] }}"
```

if you want ot use a list like this sdb = item1, sdc = item2, i take the last char of each sdx and consider 'a' =0 , 'b' = 1 and so on

i need to create custom filter for the python function `ord` which transform a char to codeascii:

the custom filter:
create a `folder filter_plugins` in same level than your playbook, create a file `customfilter.py` and i have named the filter `ord`

the file customfilters.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'ord': self.ord
        }

    def ord(self, c):
        return ord(c) - ord('a')
```

the playbook:

```
- include_tasks: lvm.yml
  with_items: '{{ lsblk_out.stdout_lines }}'
  when: sdx != 'sda'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: sdx
  vars:
    apps: ["", 'item1', 'item2']
    application: "{{  apps[sdx | last | ord] }}"
```

Comment: Thank you @Frenchy , I've used the first solution and it works :)